# How to generate a series of dates that are the first monday from a given start date and increment by 2 weeks

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataferam with a column that contains the date for the first monday of evry week between an arbitrary start date and now. I wish to generate a new column that has 2 week jumps but is the same length as the original column and would contain repeated values. For example this would be the result for the month of October where the column weekly exists and bi-weekly is the target:

```
data = {'weekly':['2018-10-08','2018-10-15','2018-10-22','2018-10-29']
                   ,'bi-weekly':['2018-10-08','2018-10-08',
                                   '2018-10- 22','2018-10-22']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

At the moment I am stuck with `pd.date_range(start,end,freq='14D')` but this does not contain any repeated values which I need to be able to groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).weekly.transform('first')
Out[487]: 
0   2018-10-08
1   2018-10-08
2   2018-10-22
3   2018-10-22
Name: weekly, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: It produces the right result but I dont understand the syntax. What is the groupby 'on=' in this? How is the call to transform working?

Comment: @seanysull np.arange(len(df))//2, this is get the divisor, since you have weekly data already , if we need to convert them to biweekly , we just need to split them into multiple groups which only contains two weeks in it